# How to make video background cover the entire page

Tags: html, css, html5-video

I have created a video background for my website but I am trying to make it cover the entire page.

My HTML:

```
<header>
    <video loop muted autoplay playsinline poster="">
        <source src="https://www.gordonmac.com/wp-content/uploads/storm-1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="http://freshsauce.test/video/FS Website-FINAL-PRORES.mov" type="video/mov">
    </video>
    <div class="banner">
       <div class="banner-text">
          Header Text Here
       </div>
    </div>
  </header>


<p>yoooooo</p>
<p>yoooooo</p>
<p>yoooooo</p>
<p>yoooooo</p>
<p>yoooooo</p>
<p>yoooooo</p>
```

My CSS:

```
body{
  margin:0;
}
header {
 position: relative;
 height: 100vh;
 min-height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 background-size: cover !important;
 -webkit-background-size: cover !important;
 text-align: center;
 overflow: hidden;
    z-index:-99;
}
video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: -100;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

As you can see the `<p>yoooooo</p>` have a white background. The codepen is https://codepen.io/mrsalami/pen/wjmgze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use css rule position:fixed; instead of position:absolute; for video tag

```
video {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: -100;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I had a play with your CSS and added a few things. I normally remove all margin/padding from all elements at the top of my CSS file.

I then changed your video position from relative to absolute, meaning that nothing will affect it.

I also removed the !important tags. I would recommend trying to avoid these at all costs, unless absolutely necessary. Even then, avoid them at all costs.

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0;
}
body{
  margin:0;
}
header {
 position: absolute;
 height: 100vh;
 min-height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 background-size: cover;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 text-align: center;
 overflow: hidden;
 z-index:-99;
}
video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: -100;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

header:before {
 content: '';
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 height: 100%;
}

header .banner {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: center;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 85%;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 font:24px 'opensans-bold', sans-serif;
 font-weight: bold;
}

header .banner-text {
 color: #f5f5f5;
 width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do some thing like this. give `position:fixed` to video. it cover and set `top, right, bottom, left` to `0`

**https://codepen.io/arpanpatel/pen/rvdjGR**

```
video {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  z-index: -100;
  width: 100%;
}
```